# Show that if $f(x)$ is continuous at $a$ then $V_{\delta}(a) \subset f^{-1}\left(V_{\varepsilon}(f(a))\right)$

Tags: real-analysis

How can i show that if $f(x)$ is continuos at $a$ then $\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0$

such that

$V_{\delta}(a) \subset f^{-1}\left(V_{\varepsilon}(f(a))\right)$

I know that how $f(x)$ is continuos at $a$ then for all $x \in V_{\delta}(a) \cap D$ we have that  $f(x) \in V_{\varepsilon}(f(a))$.

but im really stuck any hint?

Comment: What is the set $V_{\delta}(a)$?

Comment: @MikeDesgrottes is the ball with center in a and radius $\delta$

Comment: You should edit your question to be more clear. Write out the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of continuity at a. It'll become clear, from the definition, why this is true.

Comment: This is basically true by the definition of $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ continuity at $a$, plus the definitions of what the balls are and what inverse image is.